# How to retrieve data in the system, where the ubuntu has problem in booting

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, hard-drive, data-recovery

I used to work in ubuntu installed AMD assembled workstation with nvidia gpu, while starting the system after showing the bios setup goes to a black screen and freezes. The data inside the system needed, how can I retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is as follows. You will need a usb setup for a live environment such as the Ubuntu installer. You will also need an external usb drive on which to store the recovered data:

1. Boot into the live environment by choosing “Try Ubuntu”
2. Identify the partitions in the machine (lsblk command)
3. Mount the partition with the data (sudo mount /dev/sdX# /mntpoint
4. Copy the data with recursive cp commands

Ask other questions if you need more detailed help

Comment: Thank you @ PonJAr